# Vue-cli generating project stopped

Tags: node.js, vue.js

when I try to generate a project with vue-cli, its stopped, that is what i get

```
>> vue init webpack test 
? Project name test
? Project description (A Vue.js project)
```

Then I cant cancel with ctl + c or something, I hit enter and nothing, im use node v8 and npm v5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by first uninstalling the vue-cli by running `npm uninstall vue-cli -g` then uninstalling my Node.js from the control panel: [image] Then installing the latest current version(not the LTS version) of [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) then running `npm install -g npm` then install the vue-cli again using `npm install -g vue-cli`

---

***In a nutshell update Node.js and npm to the latest versions then install the vue-cli.***

---

**Update: In case you use Ubuntu or any Ubuntu base OS:**
First, uninstalling the vue-cli by running `sudo npm uninstall vue-cli -g` then uninstall your current version of Node and install the latest version from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) (install the build tools as well) then run `sudo npm install -g npm` then install the vue-cli again using `sudo npm install -g vue-cli`

Comment: I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: @RaiRomero I've just updated my answer and included Ubuntu.